# AKKA (java) - future - OnComplete.onComplete - is not called

Tags: java, akka

`OnComplete.onComplete` is not called (selected code inside `MyActor` was executed)

```
Future future = ask(actorRef, request, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

future.onComplete(new OnComplete<Object>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(Throwable throwable, Object o) throws Throwable {
     // code here is never called
  }
}, system.dispatcher());
```

my Actor:

```
class MyActor extends AsbstractActor {
    ...
    sender().tell(response, self());
    this.getContext().getSystem().stop(this.getSelf());
    ...
}
```

Comment: What if you don't shut the ActorSystem down?

Comment: May be you need to try  `Thread.sleep()` after `future.onComplete` callback

Comment: it was jsf issue (and my first project with jsf :) )